# cocos2d gives slow animation?

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

i have used cocos2d for game development.but when i use a sprite in CCLayer(inherited) to move through ccTime.but it moves very slowly.i have set in appgelegate CCDirector setAnimationInterval for (1.0/60) The code is as following:

```
-(id) init
{
if ((self = [super init]))
{
    danceSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"images.png"];
    [self addChild:danceSprite];

    // position the sprite in the center of the screen
    CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    danceSprite.position = ccp(s.width/2,s.height/2); //CCSprite
    bg_pos.x = danceSprite.position.x;
    bg_pos.y = danceSprite.position.y;
            [self scheduleUpdate];
}
return self;
```

}

```
-(void) update:(ccTime)delta
 {
CGPoint pos = danceSprite.position;
bgX = pos.x;
//bgX -= 30.0;


int newX;
newX = bgX + 1.0 * GAME_SPEED_ADJUSTMENT;
pos.x = bgX;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

> GAME_SPEED_ADJUSTMENT
>   variable/constant

to multiply with delta to get a faster movement. My start setting is always a

> minimum of 10

, in your case it's 1, so I would expect it to move rather slowly.

So it looks like

> newX = oldX + delta *
>   GAME_SPEED_ADJUSTMENT

Try this first - one might also use this to increase the difficulty of the game and globally move things faster.

If this doesn't work, just come back....

Comment: what do you mean "it gives same"? Is there no change in speed at all ? Please show your schedule method, do you provide an interval?

Comment: ps you really should use the scheme I suggested, ie using delta to compute new x and y values - this makes sure that it moves in a certain speed independently of other tasks running on your device...

Comment: I see 2 issues here: 1. Please MULTIPLY the delta into the movement as I wrote: newX = oldX * <<<<delta>>>>>> * GAME_SPEED_ADJUSTMENT and 2. more importantly, have you declared the x and y as int? Use floats, int get rounded and don't increase by the small deltas you need - we'll get this fixed sooner or later and if it's still not working please show the way you schedule as I suggest before....